# tensorflowでの学習途中、テンソルから画像を出力させる方法を教えてください。

Tags: tensorflow

tensorflowでの学習途中、テンソルから画像を出力させる方法を教えてください。
shape=(64, 40, 40, 1), dtype=float32なTensorから40×40×1の画像を出力させたいです。

Answer (score 0):

画像は２次元データ、質問のテンソルの次元は(64, 40, 40, 1)の４(3?)次元なので、何らかの変換をしなければなりません。

単純なのは、次元(64, 40, 40, 1)のテンソルを、64枚の(40,40)の２次元データ(スライス)に分けて、それぞれを画像として表示するような方法だと思います。

テンソルの全体を俯瞰するのであれば、人体のCT画像やMRI画像のように、X,Y,Zの各軸にそったスライスをつくって順序通りに表示する。あるいは、各値を球の大きさで表した３次元表示をするといった方法も有効かと思います。